# Fancy captcha jquery - drop event

Tags: jquery, draggable, captcha

I am trying to use the drop event of fancy captcha (http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin) but it never fires. This is the code (without any change from the website:

```
$("#ajax-fc-circle").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

        $(".ajax-fc-" + rand).draggable("disable");
        $("#" + options.formId).append("<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"display: none;\" name=\"captcha\" value=\"" + rand + "\">");
    },
    tolerance: 'touch'
}); 
};
```

The drop event is never fired. Has anyone had any experience with fancy captcha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this one. There is a problem with fancy captcha and latest jQuery libraries. My project was referencing the latest library from Google API. I just changed it to reference to 1.3.1 and the event fires correctly.